# Visual Studio 2015 Win32 does not optimize unused static const

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

I have a very simple application that if I build in Release mode with compiler switch /TC it will not optimaze out some variables.

for example ->

```
#include <windows.h>

static const DWORD test[32000] = { 1 };

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If this is build in Visual Studio 2015 as Win32 project with /TC switch set it will not optimize static const. But if I build as C++ it will.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: I don't see what [the `/TC` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) have to do with optimization?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize static const"? What are you expecting to happen? You are aware that `const` means something different in C than it does in C++, right?

Comment: Nothing. But for some reason it will not optimize static const. I dont think building as C should leave static const in.

Comment: Yes I know the difference. I do not understand why it would not be optimized out in C but it would be in C++. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Well it just doesn't. I think only Microsoft can answer why. Maybe they want to play it safe as many old drivers are written in C.